# The sticky menu prevents the correct scrolling to the text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have image that when user click on element on the image it scrolls down to text.
I have problem , because i have a sticky menu on the top of my website.
How can i solve problem with scroll exacly to text with include stickymenu on me website?

HTML code to example ( without sticky menu) looks like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  
  
  <style>
    html{scroll-behavior:smooth}
  </style>


<div style="width:100%;">
    <img id="img_ID" src="https://i.ibb.co/M6pJRry/kalendarium-22.png" usemap="#map" border="0" width="100%" alt="" />
</div>
<map id="map_ID" name="map">
<area shape="rect" coords="81,79,171,117" href="#1954" />
<area shape="rect" coords="142,146,334,204" href="#1954" />
<area shape="rect" coords="81,235,254,481" href="#1954" />
<area shape="rect" coords="255,234,378,407" href="#1958" />
<area shape="rect" coords="255,514,338,545" href="#1958" />
<area shape="rect" coords="315,427,483,466" href="#1958" />
<area shape="rect" coords="381,229,593,405" href="#1986" />
<area shape="rect" coords="595,243,799,403" href="#1995" />
<area shape="rect" coords="619,513,699,543" href="#1995" />
<area shape="rect" coords="678,430,821,463" href="#1995" />
<area shape="rect" coords="803,243,1058,412" href="#2001" />
<area shape="rect" coords="885,83,965,117" href="#2001" />
<area shape="rect" coords="935,143,1078,167" href="#2001" />
<area shape="rect" coords="1062,243,1288,410" href="#2009" />
<area shape="rect" coords="1135,429,1372,485" href="#2009" />
<area shape="rect" coords="1081,513,1167,541" href="#2009" />
<area shape="rect" coords="1292,236,1494,408" href="#2015" />
<area shape="rect" coords="1345,85,1424,115" href="#2015" />
<area shape="rect" coords="1389,147,1553,204" href="#2015" />
<area shape="rect" coords="1468,511,1548,546" href="#2018" />
<area shape="rect" coords="1498,225,1853,464" href="#2018" />
<area shape="rect" coords="1516,463,1643,486" href="#2018" />
<area shape="rect" coords="1419,411,1495,464" href="#2018" />
<area shape="rect" coords="1422,222,1494,232" href="#2018" />
<area shape="rect" coords="473,87,550,114" href="#1986" />
<area shape="rect" coords="521,147,679,186" href="#1986" />
</map>




<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>




<p id ="1954">
<strong>Odkrycie bakterii Lactobacillus acidophilus Er-2 317/402.</strong>Prof. Levon Akopovich Erzinkyan – naukowiec i wynalazca, dr n. technicznych i biologicznych, twórca Mikrobiologii Technicznej w Armenii – przeprowadza analizę smółki swojej wnuczki, pod kątem obecności bakterii kwasu mlekowego i odkrywa wyjątkowy szczep, wyróżniający się niezwykłą żywotnością i odpornością na antybiotyki, żółć i kwas.
</p>

<br>

<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>


<p id ="1958">
<strong>Pierwsze zastosowanie bakterii Lactobacillus acidophilus Er-2 317/402.</strong>Wnuczka prof. Erzinkyana trafia do szpitala z powodu ciężkiej infekcji jelitowej. Gdy dziewczynka nie reaguje na leczenie szpitalne, a lekarze rozkładają ręce, nie dając jej szans na przeżycie, prof. Erzinkyan wprowadza do jej leczenia bakterie Lactobacillus acidophilus Er-2 317/402. Dziewczynka zdrowieje, a szczep, który podano zostaje nazwany od jej imienia – Narine. Rok później Rząd Armenii wprowadza ten probiotyk jako obowiązkowy dodatek do mleka na oddziałach neonatologicznych i w przedszkolach. Dzięki niemu mleko staje się wartościowym zamiennikiem naturalnego pokarmu, a karmione nim dzieci nie chorują na schorzenia przewodu pokarmowego, mają lepszą odporność, fizjologię i metabolizm.
</p>

<br>


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>










<p id ="1986">
<strong>Czarnobyl, rekomendacja WHO.</strong>Po wybuchu elektrowni jądrowej w Czarnobylu, Lactobacillus acidophilus Er-2 317/402 Narine, zostaje włączony do leczenia osób z dysbiozą. Wyniki badań pokazały, że bakteria przyczynia się do normalizacji flory jelitowej i poprawy stanu zdrowia leczonych osób. Pozytywne wyniki terapii zwracają uwagę Organizacji Zdrowia, która rekomenduje stosowanie szczepu Narine w tak ekstremalnych sytuacjach.
</p>

<br>


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>













<p id ="1995">
<strong>Powstanie zakładu przy Instytucie.</strong>Na początku lat 90-tych, młody dr, Dilanyan Edward Karlenovich, staje przed groźbą  poważnej operacji. Chcąc jej uniknąć, chwyta się ostatniej deski ratunku – zaczyna przyjmować Narine w postaci jogurtu (jedynej, dostępnej w tamtym czasie formie). Szybkość i efektywność działania „leku” na tyle go zdumiewa i fascynuje, że postanawia poświęcić się badaniom nad tą niezwykłą bakterią. Otwiera pierwszy na świecie zakład produkujący tabletki z oryginalną bakterią Narine. Zakład Vitaway LLC znajduje się w najbliższym sąsiedztwie Instytutu, w którym od początku przechowywany jest szczep.
</p>

<br>


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>









<p id ="2001">
<strong>Badania w Japonii.</strong>Japońscy mikrobiolodzy z Institute Pasteur de Kyoto, przeprowadzają serię badań nad bakterią Lactobacillus acidophilus Er-2 317/402 Narine, odnosząc się do badań z 1987 roku, w których wykazali, że bakteria Narine indukuje produkcję interferonu – naturalnej substancji wytwarzanej przez komórki organizmu, odpowiedzialnej za wytwarzanie przeciwciał w celu zwalczania infekcji.
</p>

<br>


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>







<p id ="2009">
<strong>Ujawnienie informacji o stosowaniu Narine przez radzieckich astronautów.</strong>W Wielkiej Brytanii, na jaw wychodzą informacje o stosowaniu Lactobacillus acidophilus Er-2 317/402 Narine przez radzieckich astronautów. Wcześniej, ujawnienie osiągnięć naukowych dotyczących szczepu Narine, nie było możliwe, ponieważ stanowiły one tajemnicę wojskową i były regulowane przez KGB.
</p>

<br>


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>















<p id ="2015">
<strong>Otwarcie zakładu produkcji i innowacji w Japonii.</strong>Japończycy postanawiają wprowadzić produkty z bakterią Narine na swój rynek. W porozumieniu z armeńskim Vitaway LLC otwierają w Tokio zakład produkcyjny. Niestety mimo wielu przeprowadzonych badań nad bakterią i podjętych prób produkcji, nie odnoszą sukcesu. W końcu postanawiają zamawiać Narine bezpośrednio z Armenii i tak jest do dzisiaj.
</p>

<br>


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>




<p id ="2018">
<strong>Powstanie polskiej marki NARUM.</strong>Michał Toczyłowski, prawnik i przedsiębiorca, szukając ratunku, dla jednego ze swoich synów, u którego zdiagnozowano zwiotczenie mięśni (skutek pewnych działań medycznych), trafia w rosyjskiej literaturze medycznej, na wzmiankę o niezwykłej bakterii Narine. Po wielomiesięcznych poszukiwaniach udaje mu się w końcu nawiązać kontakt z producentem w Armenii. Po doświadczeniu na sobie i najbliższych, niezwykłego działania probiotyku, postanawia sprowadzić te produkty na rodzimy rynek. Tworzy markę Narum i rozpoczyna współpracę z producentem z Armenii.
</p>

<br>


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var ImageMap = function (map, img) {
            var n,
                areas = map.getElementsByTagName('area'),
                len = areas.length,
                coords = [],
                previousWidth = 1900;
            for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
                coords[n] = areas[n].coords.split(',');
            }
            this.resize = function () {
                var n, m, clen,
                    x = img.offsetWidth / previousWidth;
                for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
                    clen = coords[n].length;
                    for (m = 0; m < clen; m++) {
                        coords[n][m] *= x;
                    }
                    areas[n].coords = coords[n].join(',');
                }
                previousWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                return true;
            };
            window.onresize = this.resize;
        },
        imageMap = new ImageMap(document.getElementById('map_ID'), document.getElementById('img_ID'));
    imageMap.resize();
    return;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddleDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/tjsy3upL/)

Without this sticky menu it works perfect. But how can i do that to scroll good with sticky menu there?

Link  to my website with sticky menu : https://mynarum.com/o-nas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site is scrolling correctly. It must be quite annoying with the navbar...

What you *could* do is place an empty tag such as div, p, h1, etc and give it the proper id so the page scrolls less.

```html
<a href="#SrcollId1">To 1</a>
<a href="#HigherLink">To 2</a>


<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<p id="HigherLink">-</p>

<!-- Because the navbar blocks this super important text, tell the <a> tag to go higher. -->

<p id="SrcollId1">Super important text that is blocked by navbar...</p>


<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing which you can do is give a class to items of your body which are hiding under menu and calculate the height(margin+ padding+ height) of your fixed menu bar and add padding(padding-top = equal to height of menu bar) on all the elements.